# React Component's inline style is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created Carousel component, it returns a collection of carousel boxes, before returning it I am applying style property to every returning div, but the style is not working. What should I do to fix it?

If I created another div inside the main div and wrap the content of outer div into inner div, and apply style property to inner div 
 instead to outer div then everything is working.

```
const Carousel = (props)=>{
 return (
         <Slider {...settings}>
           { props.sectionDetails?
            props.sectionDetails.map(
             (TypeBox)=>{
               return (<div key={TypeBox.id} style={{background: 
                        TypeBox.background_color}}>
                        <h3>{TypeBox.title}</h3>
                        <p>{TypeBox.description}</p>
                      </div>
                      );
             }):"" }
        </Slider>
        );
}
```

I want only one div and style should work with this, I don't want to create another nested div.

Comment: Are you sure that Typebox has the property background_color? Because your syntax is correct.

Comment: seems like the TypeBox does not have the property background_color, can you please recheck that

Comment: @SagiRika What part of syntax is incorrect?

Comment: `style={{background: TypeBox.background_color}}` is the correct syntax. I'm 99% sure that `background_color` is just not a property of `TypeBox`.

Comment: @SagiRika, I know this is the right way, but In this way everything is working fine.
return (<div key={TypeBox.id}><div style={{TypeBox.background_color}} <h3>{TypeBox.title}</h3><p>{TypeBox.description}</p></div></div>);

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles in React is a similar with JSON.

1. The style element must be writen together with camelCase.
2. The Value of the style element must be wraped in quotes.

I don't know will it work with you'r code, but try this anyway, this is the right way to call inline style:

```
style={{backgroundColor: "TypeBox.background_color"}}
```

Or You can try to wrap Your style into backticks like this:

```
style={{backgroundColor: `${TypeBox.background_color}`}}
```

Comment: "TypeBox.background_color" will parse as string. I tried the code on codepen. It's working fine. Can you check if there is a property background_color in your sectionDetails props.

Comment: ok, but in my case value of TypeBox.background_color is coming dynamically, so it should be written as 
`  <div style={{background:TypeBox.background_color}}> `

Comment: I afraid in this case You must find other way to set styles. Why You don't want to do that in outer css file and call that with className or ID?

Comment: Because style's value is coming dynamically in my case from a backend if it would be static then how I supposed to change them in ReactJS?

Comment: Do You tried to do it using state, say we have state `bg` and the value is `TypeBox.background_color`, and in inline style write `style={{backgroundColor : ${this.state.bg}}}` or something like this. But wrap this ----> ${this.state.bg} -- into backticks

Comment: Or You can use backticks to write Your version like this `style={{backgroundColor: "backtick" ${TypeBox.background_color} "backtick" }}`

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is `style={{ backgroundColor: TypeBox.background_color }}`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have come here having similar issues, AND if you are using ReactMUI. I have a working solution.

Substitute your `div` attribute with a `<Box>` component (which is MUI's div container)

I was trying to resize panels to a specific width, based off the grandparent element.

I have the grandchild element (below) I want to dynamically update with a calculated width in pixels.

```
                  <Box 
                    className='panel panel-1'
                    ref={refPanel_1}
                    sx={formWidthStyling}
                  >
```

where upon loading the page, I grab my grandparents width using another useRef (seen below)

```
              <div className='form-inputs-container'
                ref={formRef}
              >
```

I then update my `formWidthStyling` using `useEffect`

```
  const [formWidthStyling, setFormWidth] = useState<SxProps>({});

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("FORM WIDTH ADJUSTED TO: ", formRef?.current!.offsetWidth )
    setFormWidthStyling((currState:any) => currState = {width: `${formRef?.current!.offsetWidth}px !important`});
  }, [formRef]);
```

This way, my panels adjust widths based off of it's grandparents width which is  dynamically defined by a % viewport width.

My guess is the  attribute with styling is not being triggered to re-render with the most recent styling background you want, so you need to either **set state dynamically for what you are passing into the inline style**

Hope this helps.